# RichTextBox using CFM_LINK | CFM_COLOR

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I'm trying to change the color of links in a RichTextBox. I've been using http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9196/Links-with-arbitrary-text-in-a-RichTextBox as a base for inserting links into the RTF. When adding CFM_COLOR to the dwMask it doesn't use the specified color. CFM_BACKCOLOR works fine though.

```
var cf = new CHARFORMAT2_STRUCT();
cf.cbSize = (UInt32)Marshal.SizeOf(cf);
cf.dwMask = CFM_LINK | CFM_COLOR;
cf.dwEffects = CFE_LINK;
cf.crTextColor = ColorTranslator.ToWin32(LinkColor);
```

Is there anyway to override the default hyperlink color?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation, it seems [crTextColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787883(v=vs.85).aspx#crTextColor) takes a [ColorRef](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183449(v=vs.85).aspx) object. Try converting your color to it instead. To make it easier, let's make a macro for making a color ref:

```
COLORREF RGB(
  BYTE byRed,
  BYTE byGreen,
  BYTE byBlue
);
```

Then, down a few lines in your hyperlink section:

```
...
// I don't know how LinkColor is defined here, 
// but this should put you on the right track.
var color = RGB(LinkColor.Red, LinkColor.Green, LinkColor.Blue);
cf.crTextColor = color;
```

Comment: Originally I had cf.crTextColor = LinkColor.ToARGB which wasn't giving the correct code, but ColorTranslator.ToWin32(LinkColor) does colour the code properly as long as I leave out the CFM_LINK flag. I'll try creating the COLORREF struct though. Cheers!

Comment: Yea it sounds like ToARGB wouldn't work, because it only deals with RGB values, so yea, give that a try and see if it works.